# GPS not working properly on iPhone: it knows where it is but app can't recognize it

Tags: iphone, disk-space, gps

My iPhone 6 GPS sometimes just does not work properly. I might be using Waze or Google Maps, but it just looks like it's lost. It knows where it is, because it can follow my position on the map, but the application seems like it can't fully recognize its position and usually just says it's looking for GPS signal (well, sometimes it gets crazy too and goes back all the way to my starting point back and forth).

Does anyone know what may be causing this?

The only thing I suspect is sometimes I have a very low available space on my device, but I'm not totally sure and would sure like to find out how to fix this annoying behavior.

Comment: Did you try resetting network settings? I face the same problem often and resetting network settings followed by a reboot fixes the issue. But the downside is that you loose passwords for all connected Wi-Fi access points.

Answer (score 1):

It can’t hurt to open 1 GB of free space, but your GPS is more likely an issue with location services.

1. Get a good backup
2. Disable location services entirely and power down the phone
3. Power on and enable location, verify cellular data and WiFi, bluetooth, data and cellular radios are on.
4. Try maps to locate and walk to be sure GPS is tracking
5. Take some photos

If you still are not getting gps in other apps, consider deleting the app (reminder about backup) and reinstalling. Also, check location for that specific app. Toggle off and then on. Restart. Then consider erasing the device and testing then erase and restore your backup.

Only other item is reset network settings ( know WiFi passwords are deleted from f you do this and second reminder to back up just in case ).